# How can you use .map (or any other alternative) in React for nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I happen to work with an Array that looks like this

```
Array = [
          {
            product1,
            orderedBy = [{customer1}, {customer2},.....,{customerN}]
          },
          {
            product2,
            orderedBy = [{customer3}, {customer4},.....,{customerN}]
          },
          .
          .
          .,
          {
            productN,
            orderedBy = [{customer5}, {customer6},.....,{customerN}]
          },
        ]
```

I want to render it on a table like shown below

[image]

I was hoping to achieve something like this, but it gives error

```
{orders.map((order, index) => (
  {order.orderedBy.map((customer, index) => (
    <tr>
      <td>order.productId</td>
      <td>customer.customerId</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
))}
```

I'm aware that I can create a new array with elements that are easy to render using the map function. However, I'm curious to know if there is any cleaner way to achieve this result that I may not be aware of yet.

Comment: *"but it gives error"* - And what is that error?  Can you update the question to include a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates?

Comment: The JSON you provide as sample is not valid ; it is likely that your error comes from the way you parse it so can you fix that ?

Comment: It's a syntactical error. Basically telling me that my idea of using nested ".map" functions is not possible.

Comment: Add a 'key' to the TR, and there should be no error.. unless the json format is not the one you try to consume.

Comment: @SupratikChaudhuri: Nested `.map()` calls most certainly are possible.  You can call `.map()` on any array.  Instead of assuming what the error means, try *reading it* to see what is actually says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in either any element such as `div`, but since you are filling a table, use `<React.Fragment />`, which lets you wrap several children in a faux-element. You can also make it repeat directly inside the `<table>` or `<tbody>`, if the case applies to you.

Either way, don't forget to add `key` to the mapped child:

```
{orders.map((order, index) => (
  <React.Fragment key={'order-' + index}>
    {order.orderedBy.map((customer, index) => (
      <tr key={'customer-' + index}>
        <td>order.productId</td>
        <td>customer.customerId</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </React.Fragment>
))}
```

For other cases where you can wrap in a regular element this can also work (can work with any element that accepts and displays children)

```
{orders.map((order, index) => (
  <div key={'order-' + index}>
    {order.orderedBy.map((customer, index) => (
      <tr key={'customer-' + index}>
        <td>order.productId</td>
        <td>customer.customerId</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: putting div around the table rows wont give the expected results IMHO ;)

Comment: Yes I'm stupid :) I'll clarify in the answer

Comment: You don't have to wrap the rows in anything - just return them assuring that the parent element is `tbody` in a table element.

Comment: Yes mentioned that, though we can't see the wrapping code so I didn't want to assume inside the answer code itself

Comment: I wonder if you can skip the fragment as long as the `key` on the `tr` is unique, which can be made from a combination of the `order` index and the `customer` index?  (And, if possible in the data, we should probably prefer their `Id` data values, rather than just their positional index?)

Comment: You will still need to flatten the array first, which is the issue that's causing this. It's not just a row of orders, it's a *grouped* row of orders - the grouping is what makes the code need a nested loop and not one in the first place. If the array is flattened beforehand, then the inside nesting wouldn't be necessary

Comment: In the case of the key, you're right, I was not looking deep enough into the example, an `id` is definitely better than an index as the key

Comment: @casraf: True, if the intended UI is a single table of rows and not a nested grouping then it would be better to project/transpose the data into the correct structure *before* the render and then the rendering becomes trivial.  Much better to separate the concern of data transformation from the data rendering.

Comment: I agree, you are more than welcome to add another answer and suggest this as an alternative solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your data prior to mapping over it you'll have an easier time. This example creates a new object for each customer of product *n*, and adds it to a new array. You can call `compileData` from the JSX, and `map` over the returned array of objects instead.

Note: I shifted things around in the data to ensure products and customers have their own id which you should be doing anyway.

```js
function compileData(data) {
  const arr = [];
  for (const { name: productName, orderedBy } of data) {
    for (const { id, name: customerName } of orderedBy) {
      arr.push({ id, productName, customerName });
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function Table({ data }) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Product name</td>
        <td>Customer name</td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {compileData(data).map(row => {
          return (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              <td>{row.id}</td>
              <td>{row.productName}</td>
              <td>{row.customerName}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

const data=[{id: 1, name:"product1",orderedBy:[{id: 1, name:"customer1"},{id: 2, name:"customer2"}]},{id: 2, name:"product2",orderedBy:[{id: 3, name:"customer3"},{id: 4, name:"customer4"}]}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: powderblue; }
td { border: 1px solid #565656; padding: 0.3em; text-transform: capitalize; }
thead { background-color: lightgreen; font-weight: 600; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```